# Dynamic Hyperlink Formula Excel not working

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I Have Excel 2013.

ON Sheet1 In each Range("D1:D20") cell I have use

Lang is Sheet1!A1 datavalidation List "LT;RU;EN"

`=Hyperlink(FirstNamedRangeA1,SecondNamedRange)`  formulas

`FirstNamedRangeA1 = Vlookup(A1;Translations!$A:$E;IF(Lang="LT";4;IF(Lang="RU";5;3));False)`

> For each cell it own value

`SecondNamedRange = Vlookup("More";Translations!$A:$E;IF(Lang="LT";4;IF(Lang="RU";5;3));False)`

So if i select value in Sheet1!A1 then all hyperlinks in Range("D1:D20") changes to it values from Transaltion list. I need to change link address depending on selected language.

But it works until workbook is closed first time. On reopen workbook, if i select value in Sheet1!A1 when hyperlinks start works as it wants (like url link not updated) and every time in different places and always only first Hyperlink parameter, SecondNamedRange always works corectly

This is Bug?

Comment: Are you using VBA or using these as formulas?

Comment: No VBA only Formulas

Comment: Can you clarify your final paragraph, it's a little hard to follow.

Comment: If insert `=Hyperlink(FirstNamedRangeA1,SecondNamedRange)` it works correctly until workbook is closed. It means url changes on Lang selection. But after reopen url not changing in random cells. (some cell got LT language url some RU another EN no matter what is selected in Lang) and work again only if delete Hyperlink and Paste again

Comment: Can you please show `Sheet1!A1:D5` as a picture? I'm unclear with the `A1` in your `FirstNamedRangeA1 = Vlookup(A1;Translations!...`.